# multi-statement conditions in 'if'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

when I run this code:

```
def greet(lang):
    if lang == "es" or "espanish":
        print("Hola")
    elif lang == "fr" or "french":
        print("Bonjour")
greet(input ("What is your lang: "))
```

and when I type in the **input** `fr` or `french` it's always giving me `Hola`, how I fix it?

Comment: Try `lang == "es"` or `lang == "spanish"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
def greet(lang):
    if lang == "es" or lang=="espanish":
        print("Hola")
    elif lang == "fr" or lang=="french":
        print("Bonjour")
greet(input ("What is your lang: "))
```

Comment: I think using `in` is more pythonic

Comment: it's working bro thank you,,,

Answer (score 0):

This basically evaluates to (lang == "es") or "espabish" where espanish evaluates to true, so the first is always true. Instead I would do
`lang in ("es", "espanish")`

Comment: @ALI_1999 i am actually incredibly blitzed rn, but python is barely simple enough. Anytime